# Do lines across an LCD screen indicate that it's time for it to be replaced?

Tags: lcd, display, dead-pixel

I have a 5 year old thinkpad which has suddenly developed a horizontal line across the screen. The pixels on the line look 'slow' ie. they change colour only after a while and that too not consistently. The graphics look like they're pulled across the screen and spread where the line is. I ignored this for a while but the number of such lines have increased and I now have a 'band' about 0.25cm high obscuring part of my screen.

Is this repairable or do I have to change my LCD? If the latter, I think I'll spring for a new laptop rather than try to fix this one.

If you need details, please let know.

Comment: Was it looked like this? http://imgur.com/r5YKOON

Comment: Yes but I've long since replaced that laptop. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experiences, this dictates time for a new LCD. Which in the case of a 5 year old thinkpad, it would be far less expensive to replace the laptop itself.

Answer (score 4):

That smells like a bad address line in the screen--i.e., some part of the connection, or something wrong with the circuitry, especially because the colors do change, just slowly.

I bet it's repairable, but I'm not sure at what cost.

Edit to Add: If you can find a parts box on a reseller site (such as ebay or Craigslist, no endorsement of these sites implied) you can probably swap the screen out.

I've a ThinkPad nearing its 10th birthday, but for that one it's probably time to put it out to pasture.

Comment: I'll have it checked out. Let's see. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely the screen. While they may be able to repair it (replace the screen), it would probably be expensive. I would not put money into a 5 year old system. You best solution is to replace it

Answer (score 1):

It may be the screen -- or it may be a loose connector.  If you can reasonably open your laptop and re-seat the connectors, that may solve the problem. Or it may not. Even if you pay someone to do it, it may be cheap enough to try before buying a new laptop.